# zipfile header language encoding bit set differently between Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7, python-zipfile

I would like this code to work the same when run with Python 2 or Python 3

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

with ZipFile("out.zip", 'w') as zf:
    content = "content"
    info = ZipInfo()
    info.filename = "file.txt"
    info.flag_bits = 0x800
    info.file_size = len(content)
    zf.writestr(info, content)
```

However, under Python 2 out.zip starts:

```
50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 08
```

Under Python3, it starts:

```
50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00
```

The differing part is `flag_bits`, set to `0x800` for Python 2, `0x00` for Python 3.  That's BIT11: language encoding.  BIT11 seems to get set `if filename.encode("ascii")` throws.

I tried to force this bit on by setting the flag after creating the ZipInfo object, but it gets reset back to `0x00` in `_open_to_write()`.

I wonder if anyone here has a good solution.  Ideally I'd like both outputs to *have* the flag set, because that mirrors what the jar utility does.

**EDIT:**  Updated to add the `info.flag_bits = 0x800` line just to spell out what I'm trying to achieve.  I've reproduced this on Windows:
ActivePython 3.6.0.3600, vs ActivePython 2.7.14.2717, Windows 10.
And on Linux:
Python 3.6.6 vs Python 2.7.11
In case it matters, I am running this exactly as my example, no hashbang, invoking the interpreter directly:

```
pythonX test.py
```

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken but I seem to get the output `50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00` for both Python 2 and Python 3 on my Debian machine under Python 3.5.3 and Python 2.7.13

Comment: Likewise, it's the same output on Windows with Python 2 and 3 for me (as what you show for Python 3 in your question). Sounds like something OS-dependent. What are you running?

Comment: @martineau that's still not what I want, I want the bit set for both, I've changed my question as it wasn't so clear before.  Thanks for testing this, it's useful feedback, perhaps you can post your versions.

Comment: Keeely: Got it. Your code creates a file. You want make sure a bit is set at a certain offset in that file. Seems like if nothing else you could modify the file manually after it's created using binary file I/O.

Comment: @martineau, indeed that is my last resort, but it's a pretty horrible solution.

Comment: I've reproduced this with Python 3.8.0a0 (heads/master:0d12672b30, Nov 13 2018, 09:34:21) (latest git), and raised a ticket for it:  https://bugs.python.org/issue35218.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Here's code that works for me with Python 2.7 but not with 3.6 (a bit of a mystery, it seemed to work earlier this evening):

```
$ cat zipf.py
from __future__ import print_function

from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

with ZipFile("out.zip", 'w') as zf:
    content = "content"
    info = ZipInfo()
    info.filename = "file.txt"
    info.flag_bits = 0x800
    # don't set info.file_size here: zf.writestr() does that
    zf.writestr(info, content)

with open('out.zip', 'rb') as stream:
    byteseq = stream.read(8)
    for i in byteseq:
        if isinstance(i, str): i = ord(i)
        print('{:02x}'.format(i), end=' ')
    print()
```

Run as:

```
$ python2.7 zipf.py
50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 08
```

but:

```
$ python3.6 zipf.py
50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00
```

It's certainly possible to *make* it work, by making sure the file is opened before creating the `info` entry.  However, then you must avoid `writestr`, and this only works with Python 3.6 (and seems rather abusive):

```
from __future__ import print_function

from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

with ZipFile("out.zip", 'w') as zf:
    info = ZipInfo()
    info.filename = "file.txt"
    content = "content"
    if not isinstance(content, bytes):
        content = content.encode('utf8')
    info.file_size = len(content)
    with zf.open(info, 'w') as stream:
        info.flag_bits = 0x800
        stream.write(content)

with open('out.zip', 'rb') as stream:
    byteseq = stream.read(8)
    for i in byteseq:
        if isinstance(i, str): i = ord(i)
        print('{:02x}'.format(i), end=' ')
    print()
```

It's probably the case that 3.6 resetting all the `info.flag_bits` (through the internal `open` that it does) is just incorrect, although it's not really clear to me.

#### Original answer below

I cannot reproduce this, but you're right that bit 11 in the flag bits is set if the file name is Unicode and encoding as ASCII fails:

```
def _encodeFilenameFlags(self):
    if isinstance(self.filename, unicode):
        try:
            return self.filename.encode('ascii'), self.flag_bits
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            return self.filename.encode('utf-8'), self.flag_bits | 0x800
    else:
        return self.filename, self.flag_bits
```

(Python 2.7 zipfile.py source) or:

```
def _encodeFilenameFlags(self):
    try:
        return self.filename.encode('ascii'), self.flag_bits
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return self.filename.encode('utf-8'), self.flag_bits | 0x800
```

(Python 3.6 zipfile.py source).

To get the bit set you need a filename that cannot be encoded directly in ASCII, e.g.:

```
info.filename = u"sch\N{latin small letter o with diaeresis}n" # "file.txt"
```

(this notation works with both Python 2.7 and 3.6).

> I tried to force this bit on by setting the flag after creating the ZipInfo object, but it gets reset back to 0x00 in _open_to_write().

If I add:

```
info.filename = "file.txt"
info.flag_bits |= 0x0800
```

(just after setting the filename to `u"schön"`) and run this under Python 2.7 or 3.6, I get the bit set in the header (of course the file name in the zip directory changes back to `file.txt`).

Comment: Can you post your full code if you got the bit set for filename==file.txt with Python3?

Comment: @Keeely: I deleted it after posting, but I started by copying your sample from before the last edit. It essentially matched your current sample. I ran it on FreeBSD but the behavior should be the same as long as the `zipfile` library code is the same...

Comment: thanks, but can I have your precise major+ minor versions for all Pythons used.  I have up-voted the post, but at the moment it doesn't exactly give a solution (bit set for both Python versions) so cannot accept.

Comment: One is `sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=15, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`, the other is `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`. Let me try re-creating the test, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this for the time being:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo
import struct

orig_function = ZipInfo.FileHeader

def new_function(self, zip64=None):
    header = orig_function(self, zip64)
    fmt = "B"*len(header)
    blist = list(struct.unpack(fmt, header))
    blist[7] |= 0x8
    return struct.pack(fmt, *blist)

setattr(ZipInfo, "FileHeader", new_function)

with ZipFile("out.zip", 'w') as zf:
    content = "content"
    info = ZipInfo()
    info.filename = "file.txt"
    info.file_size = len(content)
    zf.writestr(info, content)
```

Hopefully it won't break too soon, FileHeader() seems like something that won't be changing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you get the correct encoding if you do this:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("./your_file.zip", "r") as zf:
    file_list = [file.encode("cp437").decode("cp850") for file in zf.namelist()]
file_list
```